# additional logic in devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

please how and where can i place additional authentication logic in devise?

i have added a custom column called expire_date in my users table and it is a date column.

i want an additional requirement that the date there must not be later than todays date before allowing them to be authenticated.

please where can i add this logic?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Or you can override the `active_for_authentication`? method in your User model

```
def active_for_authentication?
 super && (test your dates here)
end
```

If it is inactive, it will generate a flash message about the account not being active. If you want something different like "This user is not active yet", change the setting for `:inactive` in the file `config/locales/devise.en.yml`. This is taken mostly from the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Customize-user-account-status-validation-when-logging-in).

Answer (score 1):

Create your own controller that inherits from Devise::SessionsController

> app / controllers / users /sessions_controller.rb

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
...
Overwrite the new method
...
Change what else you need to change
...
end
```

Add a new route to the routes file, and you are good to go.